# Always use the selected program, always greyed out

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, file-extension

This one is driving me nuts, I'm trying to change the default program for sln files but for some reason the "always use the selected version" is always greyed out. How do I get that little grey box ungrey.

Where have I gone wrong, and how do I fix this?

[image]